# How to get JaCoCo coverage with Sonar in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Jenkins+Plugin)
I am NOT using Maven.

My Jenkins job output says:
12:32:33.951 INFO  Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
12:32:33.961 INFO  Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SeqGen/SeqGen/jacoco.exec
12:32:35.152 INFO  Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 1201 ms

Here are my properties:

```
project.home=SeqGen
sonar.projectKey=com.skyboximaging:seqgen
sonar.projectName="SeqGen"
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=true
sources=src/java
tests=test/java
binaries=classes
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=jacoco.exec
sonar.jacoco.antTargets=test-with-coverage
```

On the Sonar server, I set General Settings > Code Coverage > Code coverage plugin to jacoco

I am very confused by the documentation at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+coverage+plugins  I am particularly puzzled by this sentence: 
    "During Sonar analysis, the Sonar Jacoco plugin will take care to attach the Jacoco agent to the JVM and to launch the unit tests."

As far as I can tell, my Ant target is not getting invoked. How does the Sonar Jacoco plugin know where to find my build.xml?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

They just released what you need : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin

Comment: Could you describe a bit more the problem that you solved? As I understood you told about https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14927 but there was not descriptions there. How can we use code coverage with jenkins & sonar & ant ?

Comment: @GregoryLo sorry did not understand ? Did you mean to post this here as I have not contributing anything for this issue

Answer (score 3):

Providing an answer for the next poor soul who spends hours trying to find out why this doesn't work.  Apparently this feature has been removed:

[Remove "sonar.jacoco.antTargets" property and related classes in the plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-97?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the name of your ant task for junit does not match the name specified in the properties.

You have specified

```
sonar.jacoco.antTargets=test-with-coverage
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+coverage+plugins), there should be an ant target with exactly the same name.  Also in this target, junit should be set to fork as well.

Comment: Another "gotcha from the doco:-  

Only specified targets would be executed. So for instance, if "test" target depends on a "compile" target, Jacoco plugin will only execute "test" target without executing first the "compile" target. In such case, a solution can be to update the "sonar" target in order declare a dependency on the "compile" target